# Render swing with graphics class

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Can you render components swing through a Graphics object?

I have a structure like this in my class:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    //Render stuff
}
```

Is it possible to create an object swing, and for that object to render i using the Graphics object?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by "render"? To draw the component without having a real component? Please explain the important details. Your question smells of possibly being an XY problem, where you ask for a code solution for a problem that may be solved in a completely different way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No I would like to render it as if it were a real component. Drawing all the Graphics class can not create a textfield as to swing. So I thought if I could adapt the component with swing would have been better.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty parsing what you just wrote above. Could you re-phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

sure, absolutely possible.

```
public class MyClass extends JComponent {
  //...
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    render(g);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it, you want to draw, but not to the screen.
One can create a `BufferedImage` (or read a background image) and create a Graphics2D object with which to draw.

```
File imgFile = new File("scenery.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

render(g);

g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", imgFile);
```

Not to forget the `g.dispose()` to releast native drawing state.